# Using IF AND to match three criteria

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup, importrange

I am trying to use an IF statement to turn a cell Yes if three conditions are met.  It's not working for the third condition.  Can anyone look at my formula and point me in the right direction? Note: I can't use array formula because there are other rows in the way.

The three conditions are:

1. The cells in D2:D say User Task
2. The cells in B2:B match the cells in E2:E of another sheet and either C2:C of that sheet say Yes or Reloaded.
3. The cells in B2:B of the other sheet match Customer.

---

```
=IF(AND(D2:D="User Task",REGEXMATCH(VLOOKUP(B2:B, {
 IMPORTRANGE("1YMBUYC6JgQke-2YWs_VZx9zqlmOdhV8WYvhTpTVxBYM", "Sheet1!E2:E"), 
 IMPORTRANGE("1YMBUYC6JgQke-2YWs_VZx9zqlmOdhV8WYvhTpTVxBYM", "Sheet1!C2:C")}, 2, 0), 
 "Yes|Reloaded")=TRUE,
 IMPORTRANGE("1YMBUYC6JgQke-2YWs_VZx9zqlmOdhV8WYvhTpTVxBYM", "Sheet1!B2:B")="Customer"), "Yes", )
```

Reference sheets:
[Test Sheet 2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17HkXo7_XzO4Zvqnu6SpLTYbeF1eS_aVL3XePyy_ghUY/edit#gid=0)
[Test Sheet 1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YMBUYC6JgQke-2YWs_VZx9zqlmOdhV8WYvhTpTVxBYM/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it goes like this:

```
=IF( (con1=true)*(con2=true)*(con3=true), do "yes", otherwise empty)
```

eg:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(($D$2:$D="User Task")*(REGEXMATCH(VLOOKUP($B2:B, {
 IMPORTRANGE("1YMBUYC6JgQke-2YWs_VZx9zqlmOdhV8WYvhTpTVxBYM", "Sheet1!E2:E"), 
 IMPORTRANGE("1YMBUYC6JgQke-2YWs_VZx9zqlmOdhV8WYvhTpTVxBYM", "Sheet1!C2:C")}, 2, 0), 
 "Yes|Reloaded")=TRUE)*
 (IMPORTRANGE("1YMBUYC6JgQke-2YWs_VZx9zqlmOdhV8WYvhTpTVxBYM", "Sheet1!B2:B")="Customer"), 
 "Yes", )))
```

[image]

Comment: Hey player0 thanks again for your reply.  I didn't want to continue the other thread because I didn't want to sound annoying haha.  I implemented that formula but it doesn't seem to be working.  Row 4 of test sheet 2 showing "yes" in column E even though all of the conditions aren't met.

Comment: Someone deleted my comment on the sheet but the issue I am having is it can't be an array formula because I don't want this applying to all of the cells in the column.  That is why I am trying to use an IF statement

Comment: if not AF then try dragging: `=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IFERROR(IF((D2:D="User Task")*(REGEXMATCH(VLOOKUP(B2:B, {  IMPORTRANGE("1YMBUYC6JgQke-2YWs_VZx9zqlmOdhV8WYvhTpTVxBYM", "Sheet1!E2:E"),   IMPORTRANGE("1YMBUYC6JgQke-2YWs_VZx9zqlmOdhV8WYvhTpTVxBYM", "Sheet1!C2:C")}, 2, 0),   "Yes|Reloaded")=TRUE)*  (VLOOKUP(B2:B, {IMPORTRANGE("1YMBUYC6JgQke-2YWs_VZx9zqlmOdhV8WYvhTpTVxBYM", "Sheet1!E2:E"), IMPORTRANGE("1YMBUYC6JgQke-2YWs_VZx9zqlmOdhV8WYvhTpTVxBYM", "Sheet1!B2:B")}, 2, 0)="Customer"),   "Yes", )), 1, 1)`